# another way but SmsManager approach to enable copy feature in a SMS (for example, manipulating SMS data)

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

In an Android application,
I need the end user see **"copy"** button on a verification code in a received SMS and simply copy the code by clicking on the **"copy"** button
Then the end user would be able to manually paste the code somewhere in the Android application

In other word I don't want to implement the automatic fetch of the verification code
Just the end user would see the "copy" button then click on the "copy" button to copy the code and finally paste it somewhere manually

Apparently **SmsManager** would do such an action
But the question is
If there is another way to aim that goal  (for example manipulating SMS data to enable copy feature in a SMS)

I searched the internet a lot and found nothing